# Установить драйвер для сетевой карты без интернета в Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер

Приобрел ноутбук HP Pavilion 14-ec0054ur, с завода на нем DOS.

Захотел установить Ubuntu 21.10. Установил, запустил, а Wi-Fi модуль не определяется.

Проблема в том что на этом ноутбуке нет ethernet разъема. Скачал с другого ноутбука драйвер, перекинул флешкой, устанавливаю, ошибка, не хватает какого-то пакета, качаю его, перекидываю, устанавливаю, не хватает еще 10 пакетов...

Что можно с этим сделать?

Используется @ x1  (Realtek RTL8852AE WiFi 6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter [10EC-A85A] [NoDB])

Comment: Можно попробовать использовать смартфон в качестве модема посредством соединение по USB, либо временно использовать внешний WIFI-адаптер.

Comment: Посмотри https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89

Comment: или как уже написали телефон или USB-Ethernet адаптер, внеший WiFI тоже можно попасть на неподдерживаемый

Answer (score 1):

Подключи телефон как усб модем (драйвера есть в Линукс). Подключи интернет и с его помощью доустанови чего не хватает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте развернуть локальные репозитории и указать их в списке источников (на примере дебиана это файл /etc/apt/sources.list, после чего необходимо выполнить апдейт). Это поможет решить проблему отсутсвующих пакетов.

При установке драйвера с вашего USB, связанные отсутствующие пакеты должны установиться автоматически из локальных репозиториев.

Записи о стандартных сетевых репозиториях необходимо закомментировать при помощи "#".